# SSRS Variable Columns in a Table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have an issue in our to display the results of Stock Locations for each item in a warehouse, whereby each item may have up to 10 locations.

In SQL, the query I have created gives me these results:

**Item     |     Description    |    Location/Qty**

AB10 | Tube 10 | E13P - 1

AB10 | Tube 10 | E15B - 3

AB10 | Tube 10 | WS14 - 5

TS14 | Pipe 14 | E12B - 6

TG15 | Garnish 15 | T15V - 8

TG15 | Garnish 15 | E13P - 5

I need the report to look like this:

**Item | Description | Location/Qty1 | Location/Qty2 | Location/Qty3 | Location/Qty4, etc**

AB10 | Tube 10 | E13P - 1 | E15B - 3 | WS14 - 5

TS14 | Pipe 14 | E12B - 6

TG15 | Garnish 15 | T15V - 8 |  E13P - 5

I need the locations and their quantites for each item for a maximum of 10 locations. Any ideas how I go about doing this. This is using SSRS 2008.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Since you say you created the query, can you change it to be based on a `PIVOT`, and only return one row per Item with the required columns already in place? Alternatively, are you able to add a column that ranks the row with the Item group, i.e. something like `Rank() over (partition by Item order by Location)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matrix report if you are willing to modify the report structure slightly like this

```
                   |            Locations                |
Item | Description | E13P| E15B| WS14| WS14 | E12B | T15V| etc
AB10 | Tube 10     | 1   | 3   |  0  | 5    | 0    | 0   |
TS14 | Pipe 14     | 0   | 0   |  0  | 0    | 6    | 0   |
TG15 | Garnish 15  | 5   | 0   |  0  | 0    | 0    | 8   |
```

Visit this link to know more about matrix report

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334(v=sql.100).aspx